# How to dismiss the Windows 8.1 Upgrade banner?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade

As of today, my Windows 8 system is displaying a large banner covering about a quarter of the screen, demanding that I upgrade to Windows 8.1 for free.  The banner helpfully informs me that that I can continue to use the computer while the upgrade is downloading.  There's a button to go to the store for the upgrade, but no other choices, such as No Thanks, Maybe Later, or Absolutely Not.

[image]

I can't find a way to dismiss the banner, and I can start programs but can't give them focus while the banner is present.  So I'm dead in the water.  How can I fix this?  Bringing up Task Manager doesn't give me any options.

My employer doesn't yet support Windows 8.1 (which is also an issue, but beyond my control) so I won't be able to connect to work if install the upgrade.  So there is no way on God's green earth that I'm going to install this upgrade now.

UPDATE: The banner went away after the second restart and I was able to run regedit as @magicandre suggested.  The banner hasn't reappeared.  So far, so good.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the exact banner?

Comment: does ur windows update settings is set to ask me everytime?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that your employer is using some software which support windows 8 but not 8.1? Afaik there are not that large a difference.

Comment: @Lenne - There are **significant** differences in the drive model between the two versions.  The number one reason an upgrade will fail is because of a driver conflict

Comment: @chipperyman - I wish I could take a screenshot!  I can't do anything when the banner is up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable the message run regedit, go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UpgradeNotification
```

and change the value `UpgradeAvailable` from `1` to `0` or [remove the Update](http://windows.mercenie.com/windows-8/how-to-install-and-uninstall-updates-in-windows-8/) [KB2885699](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2885699/en-us).

Comment: This seems to work.  Since I made the registry change the banner hasn't reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open the store from the banner, and then close the store without actually downloading the update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a powershell snip to make things easier on readers.

Step1) Open Powershell as Administator

Step2) Paste this command.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UpgradeNotification' -Name UpgradeAvailable -Value 0
#
```

As always backup the registry before making changes.

FYI, I am not going to write an uninstaller for the update, but that is plausible solution as well.